# Bind user input to UActorComponent methods in UE4.22.3 and Up

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create UActorComponent which will handle some user input.
I am doing it this way:

```
void MyComponent::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    this->InputComponent = GetOwner() ->FindComponentByClass<UInputComponent>();

    if (this->InputComponent != nullptr) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("%s InputComponent Found"), *(GetReadableName()));

        this->InputComponent->BindAction("MyAction", IE_Pressed, this, &MyComponent::ActionStart);
        this->InputComponent->BindAction("MyAction", IE_Released, this, &MyComponent:: ActionEnd);

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("%s InputComponent Binding done"), *(GetReadableName()));
    }
}
```

However component's methods never called. I found out that all the bindings gone after Pawns `SetupPlayerInputComponent` method is called. If I do all bindings inside `SetupPlayerInputComponent` all the bindings work properly.

So what is a best way to handle user input inside UActorComponent or it is not good practice at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned the bindings work if you call the functions inside `SetupPlayerInputComponent` so the easiest solution would be is to create a function in your component called `SetupInput` and call that function from your pawn's `SetupPlayerInputComponent` function.

And yes in my opinion bindings should be handled by either the controlled pawn or the player controller as thats how the ue4 game framework works.
I'd move all my inputs inside the controller if you don't have any specific pawn to control or if it's just a camera move it inside a Pawn itself.

Comment: Any I dead how can I separate input handling for different contexts?  If I have 5-10 types of suits which handle my input differently my player controller will have a lot of methods which won't be used most time

Comment: this really should not be a performance concern. You should optimize code once you find it is slow not before ;) Also the engine should be able to handle hundreds of key bindings just fine.

Comment: But this is not about the perfomance  this is about organizing the code :-)

Comment: Oh, well then i'd recommend to do the input handling and the setup related to input in blueprints? And the rest in C++. I found it annoying to do input management from C++ especially when it changes frequently and have to add more items.

Comment: Thank you. The bets advice I recently found.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the SetupPlayerInputComponent

```
InputComponent->BindAction("MyAction", IE_Pressed, MyComponentRef, &MyComponent::ActionStart);
```

As for it being good practice or not, it can have its perks, mainly to reduce clutter or reuse the Input Handlers across several unrelated subclasses of APawn.

Comment: Thank you @josip-duvancic . But what about reusability? If I have 5-10 types of suits which handle my input differently my player controller will have a lot of methods which won't be used most time